# Custom Ionic icon from Internet

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'd like to use ionic icons dynamically like this:

`<ion-icon src="https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?background=0D8ABC&color=fff"></ion-icon>`

Any idea how to make this work? (if it's possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ion-icon` component only accepts valid `.svg` files for `src='/path/to/file.svg'` attribute. As stated from the [Ionicon documentation](https://ionicons.com/usage).

> Custom icons
>   To use a custom SVG, provide its url in the src attribute to request the external SVG file. The src attribute works the same as  in that the url must be accessible from the webpage that's making a request for the image. Additionally, the external file can only be a valid svg and does not allow scripts or events within the svg element.
>
> `<ion-icon src="/path/to/external/file.svg"></ion-icon>`

The image in your `src` attribute is a `.png` format instead of a `.svg` which the component is expecting. This will then cause the component not to render the icon. If you instead use `.svg` it will turn out the way you expect.

Comment: did not think of that. makes sense!